# How to check latency with JMS PUB/SUB in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Created 2 samplers:
JMS publisher and JMS Subscriber
JMS Publisher send msgs on one queue and JMS subscriber listens msgs on another topic.
How can I link these msgs to show latency??

AUT is multithreaded and order is not guaranteed on Topic.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could save message ID or another unique message attribute into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the JMS Publisher along with the current timestamp
2. Whenever the message arrives to the JMS Subscriber you can check the attribute from the step 1 and obtain the timestamp at the time of sending. Then you can subtract the timestamp2 from the timestamp1 and the resulting value would be the "latency" you're looking for.

[JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) you might be interested in:

- [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) - gets current time in [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format and stores it into a JMeter Variable with the given name
- [__longSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) - sums given numbers (or subtracts if one of them is negative) and stores the result into a JMeter Variable

You can also consider using [sample_variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property to store the calculated delta value into .jtl result file and eventually [plot it at the reporting dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)